# Block packet by ascii or hex for Windows

Tags: hex, ascii, block, packet

I've been looking for some type of software that can filter specific packets and drop or block them for windows. Something that would block a packet that contains"Hello" for example. Based on the HEX or ASCII of the packet I wanna' block.

Basically there's a few malicious packets that can crash a service running on the windows server. I need a way to capture the packet and block it from reaching the windows server while allowing everything else to pass through as normal. Like a filter.

Comment: I would suggest fixing the service, not relying on always-perfect data.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to tho, since it's a pre compiled one. I have no source.

Comment: There's a whole API and SDK for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/porting-packet-processing-drivers-and-apps-to-wfp